# SQL server JDBC does not throw Lock timeout exception but commit successfully

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, locking

SQL server JDBC does not throw Lock timeout exception but commit successfully.

For example,

connection 1:

```
begin transaction;
select * from Foo with (HOLDLOCK) where id = 1;
```

connection 2:

```
begin transaction;
set LOCK_TIMEOUT 0;
select * from Foo with (XLOCK) where id = 1;
commit transaction;
```

In SSMS studio, it works as expected, the connection 2: lock timeout.

But with JDBC, the connection 2: lock wait for a few seconds(should be no waiting), then committed successfully without throwing any exception. A SQLException should be thrown. Anything wrong?

```
//connection1

connection1.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement stmt = connection1.prepareStatement("select * from Foo with (HOLDLOCK) where id = 1");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.closeOnCompletion();

//connection2

connection2.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection2.prepareStatement("select * from Foo with (XLOCK) where id = 1");
ResultSet resultSet = stmt2.executeQuery();
stmt2.closeOnCompletion();
connection2.commit();
```

Comment: JDBC: group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '8.2.1.jre8'

Comment: well fat-fingered that one. Your code is likely not doing what you think it is doing. Posting a pure tsql demo is not particularly useful.

Comment: added JDBC code

Comment: You need to invoke `stmt2.getMoreResults()` to get the error as it follows the result set returned by the select query.

Comment: statement.getMoreResults()? next result is resultSet or updateCount. It will not throw exception.